# Absolute positioned html element

Tags: html, css

Is it good or bad to make a web page with `position: absolute` to all element?

Comment: Depends on the design.  A gut reaction might be that it's a "bad design" but we don't know the design.  Without any specific information this is entirely subjective.

Comment: It no good or bad. Modern browsers have ignored this render differences, of course, it is lack of flexibility, only when necessary to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This completely depends on what are you attempting to achieve.  Absolute position can cause unwanted overlap in some cases, and in addition will take the specific element out of the document flow, but in many cases this may be the desired effect and can be accounted for.

In addition, using absolute positioning inside a parent element with relative positioning can allow you to place elements in a position that is relative to their parents constraints.  Refer to this article to learn more: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Edit: Missed the fact that you were planning on doing this for every element.  This is a very poor way of designing a web page, unless you were doing this for a small number of elements where your desired layout could not be achieved by more conventional means.  The issue is that you'll be required to set the top and left coordinates for every single element - if you decided to move one element, or change its size, suddenly you'll have to change the positions of all your elements.

Comment: The question was about absolute positioning on all elements, not just a few.

Comment: @PeterWooster: And indeed the design might work on all elements, if it calls for that.  The question is pretty ambiguous about that, offering no specifics.  Not that this is a code review or UI review site anyway, so it would just end up being off-topic.

Comment: I frequently use absolute within relative positioning for very specific purposes, but wholesale use of this tends to result in a very inflexible site.

Comment: I think your edit is what I said in my answer. So now I can upvote yours.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is made for a purpose...There is nothing like good or bad about position absolute. It depends on one's need to use position as relative or absolute. If the person wants the element to be positioned relative to the other elements then position relative is used. If the element has to be positioned at a place irrespective of the other elements then absolute is used. So it completely depends on the design.

Answer (score -1):

It is terrible web design as nothing can flow and you won't have a chance of making it responsive.  I've seen designs like this done in Dreamweaver and they are impossible to maintain. If the content changes, the design will need to be completely redone.